# Are there any disadvantages of enabling LTE on Nexus 4?

Tags: nexus-4

I've heard it is possible to enable LTE for the Nexus 4. Are there any disadvantages of this? I assume there is a reason why it isn't enabled by default.

Comment: Related: [Enabling LTE on Nexus 4](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89218/enabling-lte-on-nexus-4)

Answer (score 1):

To enable LTE, you run a older build of the modem firmware or a hybrid custom build. They might have security issues theoretically.

Practically, the only downside is you might have lower battery life.
LTE on Nexus 4 is only supported on Band 4. Make sure your carrier uses that band for LTE. If you experience any issues with the modem, you can reflash the newer build easily via fastboot or recovery.